# Deployment of Office Web Add-In on Excel desktop and Excel Online

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am having issues deploying an Excel Web Add-In. I would like to deploy it for internal use and not go through store. I have tried 2 different methods of deployment as documented on https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish

The first method I tried is [Office 365 admin center preview](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-Ins-in-Office-365-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE). With this method, I can only see the Web Add-In on Excel desktop and not Excel Online.

Then I tried, [SharePoint catalog](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog.htm). With this method, I can only see the Web Add-In on Excel Online but not on Excel desktop.

How do I get the web add-in to show on both Excel desktop and Excel Online without going through the Office store?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using add-in commands?  I ask because it has implications on which deployment methods are supported.

Comment: I only have 1 button which does the ShowTaskpane action. Also as mentioned, I can get it to show up in either Excel Online or Excel 2016 Desktop depending on the deployment method that I use. However, I cannot get it to show on both Excel Online and Excel desktop at the same time.

Comment: _"Then I tried, SharePoint catalog. With this method, I can only see the Web Add-In on Excel Online but not on Excel desktop."_ Have you added your SP Catalog website to the list of trusted add-in locations in Excel desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Centralized Deployment feature within Office 365 Admin Center should have the Add-In show up in Office Online by EOW. We are rolling it out across our environments and should be there shortly

Thanks
Phil

Comment: To add to what Phil said. Yes, Centralized Deployment is the way to go. The SharePoint Add-in Catalog doesn't support add-in commands; it happens to work in Online clients but it won't work on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys! Appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry Phil, what if you already added an add-in using Office 365 Admin Center and you would like to: 1) add a second add-in (the button 'Add an Office Add-in' is now missing) 2) remove the added add-in (i can't find a 'manage add-in' console)? Thanks! :)

Comment: Phil, just wondering when would the feature be released. Any estimated time? Thanks.